# How do I pass array from one controller to another in the same thread in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

So, I have the following structure:

```
Thread
     Bean PreProcessor
     Controller1
     Controller2
```

Bean PreProcessor creates an arrayList named "orders" by:

```
List order = new ArrayList();
order.add("Hello");
props.put("oList", order);
```

Controller1 contains a processor with the following code:

```
List order = props.get("oList");
order.add("test1");
props.put("oList", order);
```

Controller2 contains a processor with the following code:

```
System.out.println(props.get("oList"));
```

Now, when I run this, what I want to output at console is:

```
[Hello, test1]
```

because Controller1 has added test1 in "oList", right? Instead, I see only

```
[Hello]
```

It's like Controller2 is using the original list. Why is that, and what can I do to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change from

```
Thread
 Bean PreProcessor
 Controller1
 Controller2
```

to

```
Thread
 Bean Processor
 Controller1
 Controller2
```

because the `PreProcessor` is executed before each sampler and in your case he reset the list with only `"Hello"` element